# How to draw a PDF file with different font size?

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, pdfrenderer, pdf-rendering

I am currently working on a PDF Reader application. I draw PDF files in a tiled layer with animation.

Now I want to draw PDFs with different font size (not the size specified in PDF). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really possible to do this right, given the nature of the PDF.

Even if you will be able to somehow get in between reading and drawing of PDFs you'll get messed up output in the end.

PDF pages are pretty much fixed in layout and changing font sizes won't make text and other page elements to move and wrap like HTML pages, for example.

Comment: are you have idea on what kind of approach is follow by the kindle or iBook for do this functionality.

Comment: Kindle uses MOBI and iBooks uses ePub (both formats are not PDF-based) for this. As far as I know, both formats are essentially zip files  containing HTML + images + metadata + DRM-related stuff.

Comment: Ok. But if i use epub file then i have to show data in WebView.
My question is How to give page curl animation in webView.

Comment: I guess you should ask a *new* question then.